# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whie swicth portrait and landspace (staggeredgridview library)

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, landscape-portrait

I parse image url forum json array and add them staggeredgridview So the layout looks like pinterest :)

for switch Orientation landspace to portrait or portrait to landspace ı creat two layout file one of them is layout-port(it has 2 column) the other is layout-land(it has 3 column).

when ı try switch land to port it's chancge correctly but port to land return  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

[image: landspace]

[image: portrait]

the error

```
    09-05 20:34:55.412: E/ViewRootImpl(26391): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
09-05 20:35:00.182: E/dalvikvm(26391): The following issues were seen:
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.populate(StaggeredGridView.java:965)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.onLayout(StaggeredGridView.java:919)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:476)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14618)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4491)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2191)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1218)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4975)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-05 20:35:04.302: E/AndroidRuntime(26391):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "catName";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static String categoryId;

// token ve tokenValue
static String Token = "token";
static String tokenValue = "********";

private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
private static String[] urlArray;

SlidingMenu menu;
jsonParser jsonParser;
JSONArray jArray;
ListView lvSiliding;
PARSEJSONCATEGORYCONTENT categoryContent;
PARSEJSONCATEGORY categoryName;

public static StaggeredGridView gridView;
Display display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay();

    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidth(5);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setBehindWidth(400);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);

    jsonParser = new jsonParser();
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lvSiliding = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_sliding_menu);

    gridView = (StaggeredGridView) MainActivity.this
            .findViewById(R.id.staggeredGridView1);

    categoryName = new PARSEJSONCATEGORY();
    categoryName.execute();

    categoryContent = new PARSEJSONCATEGORYCONTENT();
    categoryContent.execute("6");

    lvSiliding.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            categoryId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryID))
                    .getText().toString();

            menu.toggle();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), categoryId,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            categoryContent = new PARSEJSONCATEGORYCONTENT();
            categoryContent.execute(categoryId);

        }
    });

}


    // parse sliding menu item
private class PARSEJSONCATEGORY extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String urlCatName = "******";

        jArray = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrltoCategoryName(urlCatName, Token,
                tokenValue);

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String catName = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);
                String catID = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                Log.d("catName", catName);
                Log.d("catID", catID);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, catName);
                map.put(TAG_ID, catID);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                        TAG_CATEGORY, TAG_ID }, new int[] {
                        R.id.categoryName, R.id.categoryID });
        lvSiliding.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }
}

    // parse girdView item
private class PARSEJSONCATEGORYCONTENT extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        String identifier = params[0];
        String urlCatContent = "*******";

        jArray = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrltoCategoryContent(urlCatContent,
                Token, tokenValue, identifier, "0", "10");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject k = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String catName = k.getString("ipad_URL");

                Log.d("ipad_URL", catName);

                list.add(catName);
                urlArray = new String[list.size()];
                list.toArray(urlArray);

            }

            String arrayLenght = Integer.toString(urlArray.length);
            Log.d("arrayLenght", arrayLenght);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return urlArray;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String[] args) {

        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin);

        gridView.setItemMargin(margin + 10); // set the GridView margin

        gridView.setPadding(margin + 10, margin + 10, margin + 10,
                margin + 10); // have the margin on the
        // sides as well

        StaggeredAdapter adapter = new StaggeredAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.id.imageView1, urlArray);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        categoryContent.cancel(true);

    }

}

}
```

layout_land

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:staggered="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
    android:id="@+id/staggeredGridView1"
    staggered:numColumns="3"
    staggered:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

layout-port

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:staggered="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
        android:id="@+id/staggeredGridView1"
        staggered:numColumns="2"
        staggered:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: update mainActivity and layout files

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in [`StaggeredGridView`](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/blob/master/src/com/origamilabs/library/views/StaggeredGridView.java) `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. It assumes that the column count stays the same, while you have different number of columns for layout and portrait resources.

Good for you that it's open source and you can fix it :)

As a quick workaround, you can keep the column count same for both orientations, or try calling `setSaveEnabled(false)` on the SGV so that `onSaveInstanceState()` does not get called.

Comment: https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/issues/16 that's the solution. thanks your advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this, based on the following link:

[NullPointerException after screen orientation change #16](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/issues/16)

Will write down the steps to get it solved:

- navigate to StaggeredGridView library inside your eclipse
- locate and open StaggeredGridView.java
- locate "populate" method
- there is a for loop inside, replace it with this for loop:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i<colCount; i++){
      //final int offset =  top + ((mRestoreOffsets != null)? Math.min(mRestoreOffsets[i], 0) : 0);
      int offset = top;
      if((mRestoreOffsets != null) && mRestoreOffsets.length == colCount)
          offset +=  Math.min(mRestoreOffsets[i], 0);
      mItemTops[i] = (offset == 0) ? mItemTops[i] : offset;
      mItemBottoms[i] = (offset == 0) ? mItemBottoms[i] : offset;
  }
  ```
- save then run your application and enjoy ;-)